# How to pass struct to a new thread (C++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, struct, winsock

So, I am writing a small winsock app and I need to make a multi-client server.
I decided to use threads for every new connection, the problem is that I don't know how to pass multiple data to a thread, so I use struct.

Struct:

```
typedef struct s_par {
    char lttr;
    SOCKET clientSocket;
} par;
```

_stdcall:

```
unsigned __stdcall ClientSession(void *data) {
    par param = data;
    char ch = param.lttr;
    SOCKET clntSocket = param.clientSocket;
    // ..working with client
}
```

Main:

```
int main() {
    unsigned seed = time (0);
    srand(seed);
    /*
    ..........
    */
    SOCKET clientSockets[nMaxClients-1];

    char ch = 'a' + rand()%26;
    while(true) {
         cout << "Waiting for clients(MAX " << nMaxClients << "." << endl;

         while ((clientSockets[nClient] = accept(soketas, NULL, NULL))&&(nClient < nMaxClients)) {
          par param;
          // Create a new thread for the accepted client (also pass the accepted client socket).
          if(clientSockets[nClient] == INVALID_SOCKET) {
               cout << "bla bla" << endl;
               exit(1);
           }
           cout << "Succesfull connection." << endl;
           param.clientSocket = clientSockets[nClient];
           param.lttr = ch;
           unsigned threadID;
           HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &ClientSession, &param, 0, &threadID);
           nClient++;
    }
```

The problem is that I get errors with data type conversion. Maybe someone could suggest an easy fix with passing this struct to a thread?

Comment: Which error? And what´s `unsigned __stdcall ClientSession(*data)` ? There´s a type missing

Comment: I get error in stdcall function: "conversion from 'void * ' to non-scalar type par(s_par) requested".

Comment: The socket interface is designed to allow a single thread to process an arbitrary number of sockets efficiently. Using a thread per socket is extremely inefficient, though arguably simpler to write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With each round of your `while`-loop you're doing two ill-advised activites:

- Passing the address of an automatic variable that will be destroyed with each cycle of the loop.
- Leaking a thread `HANDLE` returned from `_beginthreadex`

*Neither* of those is good. Ideally your thread proc should look something like this:

```
unsigned __stdcall ClientSession(void *data) 
{
    par * param = reinterpret_cast<par*>(data);

    char ch = param->lttr;
    SOCKET clntSocket = param->clientSocket;
    // ..working with client

    delete param;
    return 0U;
}
```

And the caller side should do something like this:

```
par *param = new par;
param->clientSocket = clientSockets[nClient];
param->lttr = ch;
...

HANDLE hThread = (HANDLE)_beginthreadex(NULL, 0, &ClientSession, param, 0, &threadID);
if (hThread != NULL)
    CloseHandle(hThread);
else
    delete param; // probably report error here as well
```

That should be enough to get you going. I would advise you may wish to take some time to learn about the [C++11 Threading Model](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread). It makes much of this considerably more elegant (and portable!).

Best of luck.